# MongoDB: Project to array item with minimum value of field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose my collection consists of items that looks like this:

```
{
    "items" : [
        {
            "item_id": 1,
            "item_field": 10
        },
        {
            "item_id": 2,
            "item_field": 15
        },
        {
            "item_id": 3,
            "item_field": 3
        },
    ]
}
```

Can I somehow select the entry of `items` with the lowest value of `item_field`, in this case the one with `item_id` 3?

I'm ok with using the aggregation framework. Bonus point if you can give me the code for the C# driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` expression in the following way.

The below query will set the `initialValue` to the first element of `$items.item_field` and followed by `$lt` comparison on the `item_field` and if true set `$$this` to `$$value`, if false keep the previous value and `$reduce` all the values to find the minimum element and `$project` to output min item.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
         $project:  {
            items: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$items",
                    initialValue:{ 
                         item_field:{ 
                            $let: { 
                                vars: { obj: { $arrayElemAt: ["$items", 0] } },
                                in: "$$obj.item_field"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    in: {
                          $cond: [{ $lt: ["$$this.item_field", "$$value.item_field"] }, "$$this", "$$value" ] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that this should be more efficient than the `unwind` solution?

Comment: It is space efficient. I think it won't matter that much  for smaller dataset but in larger datasets unwind may be slower. You have to compare both solutions for time efficiency for your dataset.

Comment: My understanding is that the `unwind` solution also involves a sort which is O(n * log g) while `reduce` is O(n).

Comment: Here you go https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/TaL810asIMk/5n4dmPm0AgAJ

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to seperate items entries.
Then [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by  item_field asc and then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

```
db.coll.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58edec875748bae2cc391722"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "item_id" : 1,
            "item_field" : 10
        },
        {
            "item_id" : 2,
            "item_field" : 15
        },
        {
            "item_id" : 3,
            "item_field" : 3
        }
    ]
}

db.coll.aggregate([
  {$unwind: {path: '$items', includeArrayIndex: 'index'}}, 
  {$sort: { 'items.item_field': 1}},
  {$group: {_id: '$_id', item: {$first: '$items'}}} 
])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58edec875748bae2cc391722"), "item" : { "item_id" : 3, "item_field" : 3 } }
```

Comment: Could you possibly describe how to implement this using the C# driver?

Comment: Sorry, I don't knwow C#. According to the [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/aggregation/), it should look like : `var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind(new BsonDocument { { "path", "$items" } })
    .Sort(new BsonDocument { { "items.item_field", 1 } })
    .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$_id" }, { "item", new BsonDocument("$first", "$items") } });
var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

We can get expected result using following query

```
db.testing.aggregate([{$unwind:"$items"}, {$sort: { 'items.item_field': 1}},{$group: {_id: "$_id", minItem: {$first: '$items'}}}])
```

Result is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58edf28c73fed29f4b741731"), "minItem" : { "item_id" : 3, "item_field" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58edec3373fed29f4b741730"), "minItem" : { "item_id" : 3, "item_field" : 3 } }
```

Comment: This gives me a single result. What if I want to get the minimum item of every document in the collection?

Comment: I just stumbled over the `$reduce` operator. Can it be used in a `$project` step to get the minimum array item?

Comment: Could you possibly describe how to implement this using the C# driver?